Preparation of multivariate time series data
I am doing a university project on index/stock price prediction.
I plan to use a combined cnn-lstm model, and I have several different types of data: Open High Low Close Volume, values, fundamental data such as unemployment and various rates, technical indicators like RSI, MACD and others, and moving averages like SMA, EMA, WMA and etc. At this moment I am using the following transformations

for these OHLCs - simple differentiation
for fundamental data - logarithmization
for moving averages - subtract the candle opening value from the value of this moving average
indicator values unchanged

Then I use StandardizeNormalizer for all dataset.
I also tried normalizing (robust scaling, standardization, minmax scaling too) each sequence separately, and differentiating all the data, but it was not effective
And i think my current approach is not effective either. What is the best way to prepare this type of data for the network?

Just as a thought, wouldn't things like the moving averages be redundant data? These are derived from the OHLCs which I'm assuming you are also supplying to your model. I believe including these just adds noise to the data. Do you agree?
